# Allocation unit for exFAT on macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount, macos-mojave

I've spent the last few days researching how to get exFAT formatted drives to work on macOS without finding any authoritative information on the subject. Many seem to throw their hands up and declare that macOS can't mount exFAT drives for some reason or another.

I've come to believe that it is the default file allocation unit size that Windows assigns to exFAT formatted drives that can often be the culprit, but I can find no information about what the file allocation unit *should* be used for compatibility with macOS?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, it's not something I've ever struggled with - I just tried formatting an SD as ExFAT on the Mac, moved it to windows & reformatted it there, both times at defaults, both times worked perfectly. Tested both MBR & GUID, no difference.

Comment: When most people try to connect an external hard drive formatted with the exFAT file system to macOS, it will mount after a delay of minutes or hours or perhaps never at all.

Comment: Compare the same drive formatted as MBR & GUID; ExFAT, HFS & NTFS. There is nothing inherently 'slow' about an ExFAT drive on a Mac, it has native read & write capability. NTFS is read-only by default, but write can easily be added by 3rd party drivers.

Comment: It's not about read/write speed. It's about difficulty mounting the drive in the first place. If you search for "macos exfat won't mount" you will find plenty of others with the same problem, which still doesn't seem to have a concrete solution.

Comment: I never mentioned read/write speed. I suggested to test the same drive in the same enclosure in 6 different format types & see if there's a noticeable &/or repeatable pattern. Finding others with a similar issue but no conclusion gets us nowhere.

Comment: Yes, FAT32 and HSF work just fine. NTFS loads, but is read-only as you said. Then tried exFAT again, which reproduced the problem: It takes anywhere from a few minutes to many hours for macOS to mount the drive.

Comment: You're not really giving enough detail about your testing method; so it's impossible to know what you might be missing, or where the issue might be rooted. All I can say is, it doesn't happen here, across many Macs & a few PCs.

Comment: In my case [it was](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336633/92892) the 1024K value - when I re-formated my external disk to exFAT with 1024K allocation unit size it started to mount on Mac OS normally.